# Multiple html stuff stuff stuff

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have jquery code that successfully replaces a whole column of buttons (when one is clicked) with a short html line "

**new html**

Comment: Please provide HTML, as well

Comment: `navigate through different links without refreshing the page` use ajax

Comment: What "link" and "fancy buttons" are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry, just buttons that will redirect the user to different scripture chapters. Like in scriptures.byu.edu

Comment: And that's the thing, as soon as I put more HTML code in the jquery, it stops working. I don't want to replace it with a simple sentence, but with lots of lines of HTML to input buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand the question correctly it sounds like you want to do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').click(function(){myFunction()});
});
function myFunction() {
  $('#stuff').empty().append("<p>new html</p>")
}
```